# Make <p> change color depending on month in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, colors

On a our website, I mention opening hours. We are open on 6 days, but from October-March we are closed on Tuesdays. I want this to be shown in red from October-March under the table with opening hours. I managed to do this, But I use document.write and quite some javascript. From what I have read, inner.html would be quicker in my case. But I can't manage to get it working with document.write. Neither do I manage to get a leaner code.

This is what I currently have:

```
                    <h3>Openingstijden</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Maandag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Dinsdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Woensdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Donderdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Vrijdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Zaterdag:</td><td>9:00-17:00</td></tr>
                </table>
                <p id="dinsdag">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten</p>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var d=new Date();
                    var month=new Array();
                    month[0]="<font color=\"#a60000\">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.<\/font>";
                    month[1]="<font color=\"#a60000\">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.<\/font>";
                    month[2]="<font color=\"#a60000\">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.<\/font>";
                    month[3]="Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.";
                    month[4]="Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.";
                    month[5]="Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.";
                    month[6]="Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.";
                    month[7]="Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.";
                    month[8]="Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.";
                    month[9]="<font color=\"#a60000\">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.<\/font>";
                    month[10]="<font color=\"#a60000\">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.<\/font>";
                    month[11]="<font color=\"#a60000\">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.<\/font>";
                    var n = month[d.getMonth()];
                    document.write(n);
                </script>
```

I have tried to put the sentence in as text

and use inner.html to change the color, but I can't manage to actually change the sentence. I have searched a lot of tutorials, but my javascript knowledge is yet to limited to convert something to what I need. I have spend about 1,5 full days on this thing now. I do however want to learn and I'm not asking for complete scripts that are already finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to print one sentence that applies to the current month and have it coloured in red if it's applicable or normally-coloured if it's not.

If you use the element.

```
<div id="dinsdag">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten</div>
```

You can use the following JavaScript command to change the text:

```
document.getElementById("dinstag").textContent = "New Text";
```

Or to change the colour of the text then you can do:

```
document.getElementById("dinstag").style.color = "#a60000";
```

You can also use [CSS classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to have different text styles/colours and I'd generally recommend this instead of using the font tag or in-line styles.

For the conditional part, to decide whether or not to write in red, you can do something like:

```
if (currentMonth >= 9 || currentMonth <=2) {
    // change text and/or colour of element...
}
```

Comment: Looks very good. But my javascript knowledge is even more limited as I thought:P
I now have:


`code`
<p id="dinsdag">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (currentMonth >= 9 || currentMonth <=2) {
document.getElementById("dinsdag").style.color = "#a60000";
}
</script>
`code`

But this doesn't change the color? Why not.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but you need to declare the "currentMonth" variable.  Try adding `var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();` before the "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I made changes to all lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/razorcd/tdL7x/1/

```
            <h3>Openingstijden</h3>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Maandag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Dinsdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Woensdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Donderdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Vrijdag:</td><td>9:00-18:00</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Zaterdag:</td><td>9:00-17:00</td></tr>
            </table>
            <div id="dinsdag">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten</div>


                var d=new Date();
                var month=new Array();
                month[0]='<p style="color:#a60000">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>';
                month[1]='<p style="color:#a60000">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>';
                month[2]='<p style="color:#a60000">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>';
                month[3]="<p>Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>";
                month[4]="<p>Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>";
                month[5]="<p>Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>";
                month[6]="<p>Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>";
                month[7]="<p>Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>";
                month[8]="<p>Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>";
                month[9]='<p style="color:#a60000">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>';
                month[10]='<p style="color:#a60000">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>';
                month[11]='<p style="color:#a60000">Van 1 oktober t/m 31 maart dinsdags gesloten.</p>';
                var n = month[d.getMonth()];
                //document.write(n);

                //new lines
                var lastLine = document.getElementById("dinsdag");   //this will select the html element id="dinstag"
                lastLine.style.color="red";             //this will change the text color of the element

                lastLine.innerHTML = "";        //this will clean everything in <div id="dinsdag">
                for (var i=0; i<month.length-1;i++){
                    lastLine.innerHTML += month[i];      //this will add new paragraph inside the p
                }
```

This will only make your `<p id="dinstag">` red:

```
               //new lines
                var lastLine = document.getElementById("dinsdag");   //this will select the html element id="dinstag"
                lastLine.style.color="red";             //this will change the text color of the element
```

this works but there are more practical solutions to do this. where you write the text in HTML only and then change the colors only with CSS. If you want I can make you an example.

Comment: You mean writing the sentence in HTML and changing the color in CSS? That would be great.
Your examples shows 12 sentences.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/razorcd/tdL7x/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/razorcd/tdL7x/2/)   - this will make the last line red. If you want more functionality please explain.

Comment: Well, just as my code did: I wan't it to be red from Oct-March. But My code was a bit large and I think it increased the loading time.
So functionality should be the same.

Comment: Like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/razorcd/tdL7x/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/razorcd/tdL7x/3/)  Just edit the text as you like.